# How to make error message appear when 2nd number in division is equal to 0 using functions VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get return false when a/b where b is equal to 0 so that my error message appears to the user. So far I've managed to do a check within my sub but I need the check to be within the function. Currently, I get a infinity as the result, when for example 7 is divided by 0. I've basically made a pretty basic calculator and would appreciate any help.

Function:

```
Private Function validationCheck() As Boolean
    ' The following checks if the two fields are numerical values, are not blank and if the 2nd number is not zero
    'The latter is for the purpose of division
    'If the fields meet the above conditions then true is returned
    'Else if either one is not met, then false is returned
    If IsNumeric(txt1stNumber.Text) And txt1stNumber.Text <> "" And IsNumeric(txt2ndNumber.Text) And txt2ndNumber.Text <> "" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Division Sub

```
 Private Sub btnDivide_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDivide.Click

    'The following sub is the code for the division button.
    'First it checks whether false is returned from the ValidationCheck funtion
    'If so, an error message is shown
    'Else if true is returned, then the values are divided together to form the result

    If validationCheck() = False Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a numerical value for both fields. Also, field cannot be left blank.")
    ElseIf validationCheck() = True Then
        lblResult.Text = Val(txt1stNumber.Text) / Val(txt2ndNumber.Text)
    End If
```

Comment: If you think about it for a bit then you'll surely come up with If Val(..) = 0 Then lblResult.Text = "Error".

Comment: Within the function? @HansPassant

Answer (score -1):

**You can add one more condition into you function to evaluate txt2ndNumber.Text like this, then if the number b is 0 or 00 like this this will also return false.**

```
  Private Function validationCheck() As Boolean
     If IsNumeric(txt1stNumber.Text) And txt1stNumber.Text <> "" And IsNumeric(txt2ndNumber.Text) And txt2ndNumber.Text <> "" Then
        Dim number As Double = txt2ndNumber.Text
        If number = 0 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
     Else
       Return False
     End If
  End Function
```